# Add TCP Options

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, netfilter

Is there any easy & fast way to add TCP options to the SKB packet like Window scaling factor or Time stamp with C on netfilter.
Or if any body has example it would be perfect to see.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastest way is by using `sysctl` and following are various [options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sysctl#Networking), but as you are interested in window size and timestamp are below:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps
```

The command to control them is:

```
sudo sysctl -w <option=123>
```

Otherwise you can control it programatically like the way timestamp is controlled either in software or hardware in this [guide](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/02/06/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-sending-data/#timestamping).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Is that work for created packet on netfilter in kernel module  ? I have tryed before but did not succeded

Comment: It should, because `sysctl` is actually meant for runtime. Netfilter is above the network stack and if used along side will mingle with the configuration. Better to `sysctl` from netfilter itself. `sudo sysctrl -w net.netfilter.<>` You can find all the available configuration options [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.txt)